# Is it possible to put all data access related methods in a separate class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I like having separate classes, one class represents the entity, and that a separate DAO (database access object).

Is this possible with rails and active record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of what you would put into a DAO is already hidden inside of `ActiveRecord` anyway, so there's not much of a need to split these up. But, if you insist you can split out whatever methods you want into a separate `Module` and then `include` it in your model.